# How to delete a registry key on reboot?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-registry, administrator

I know how to delete/rename files on reboot http://blog.notfaqs.com/2007/10/registry-rename-file-on-reboot.html. But would like to find out how to delete registry keys on reboot as well.

I want to delete the Symantec Endpoint Protection key but I cannot. I tried to give myself permission but "Access Denied". I even tried using the NT AUTHORITY/SYSTEM account which is supposedly the highest privilege account but unfortunately it still doesn't work.

How do I delete registry keys on the next reboot?

Comment: [5 Ways to Solve Error While Deleting Key Problem When Editing Restricted Registry](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/full-control-permission-to-delete-or-edit-restricted-windows-registry/)

Comment: You may have to disable Semantic services before the reboot. If a service (or driver) is already running it might be preventing the deletion.

Comment: Nope no service/process running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not simply uninstall SEP normally?

To answer the question though... I am not in front of a Windows machine to verify right now, but IIRC the main SEP service is not listed in services.msc, i.e. the Services Control Panel applet. Try a RunOnce entry with something like this, proceeding at your own risk because deleting the wrong key in the Registry can irreparably damage your OS:

```
cmd.exe /c "c:\path\to\Symantec Endpoint Protection\bin\smc.exe" -stop && ping -n 60 127.0.0.1 && reg delete "HKLM\Software\path\to\the\key" /f
```

Info on RunOnce, et al., can be found [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/junfeng/archive/2006/09/19/761765.aspx). The ping... gives you a 60 second pause for the service to shut down. Smc.exe returns immediately as I recall.

All that said, if the only thing preventing the deletion of the key is that the SEP service is running, you can try running the smc -stop command first as an admin, then deleting the key from within regedit.